# Values of an indexed array in select dropdown option

Tags: php

I want to get the array values in dropdown option menu.**This is my code so far**

```
<?php
$names=array("jan","feb","mar");
foreach($month_names as $mn)
{
echo "<select>";
echo "<option>$mn</option>";
echo "</select>";
}
 ?>
```

But the code is creating a new select tag for each value.

How can I Get all  array value inside a select tag?

Any  help is   much appriciated, thanks!

Regards: Amit Perez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code, In your code you were including `<select></select>` inside foreach loop, that's why you were getting 3 select tag.

```
<?php

$names=array("jan","feb","mar");

echo "<select>";
foreach($month_names as $mn)
{
  echo "<option>$mn</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code as follows

```
<?php
    $month_names=array("jan","feb","mar");
    echo "<select>";
    foreach($month_names as $mn)
    {
    echo "<option>$mn</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    ?>
```